# Integrate facebook sdk to track event in app

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-analytics

I have tried to integrate facebook analytics to my app which was generated by expo but got error

```
Undefined is not an object( evaluating AppEventsLogger.logEvent)
```

I have tried to use `expo eject` to use expokit and then add the following code

```
import {AppEventsLogger} from 'react-native-fbsdk';
AppEventsLogger.logEvent('battledAnOrc');
```

Is there anyone add facebook analytics to app which generated by expo before?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour since `react-native-fbsdk` includes native code (Any library that includes a `react-native link` step in its installation instructions)

Currently, there are no built-in modules in Expo that have made that module available. [It can be seen that](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/full-facebook-sdk) we are working hard at the moment.

If you want to use a module, you need to make the app a stand-alone app.

You can run this `expo eject` and `yarn add react-native-fbsdk` and `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`